# Problem with routes and mod-rewrite (if not absolute i don't get CSS, JS or images)

Tags: .htaccess, routes

i updated the code from my website to a 'better' veersion i think,

it works fine but when i try to implement the friendly URL and load it, works, but with no CSS, Javascript or images,
but if i corret the routes for the css to http://website/css/style.css (instead of ./css/style.css) it i do see the CSS properly loaded,

any idea why?

Example: http://keepyourlinks.com/link1.php?id=25 VS http://keepyourlinks.com/keep/25/series-yonkis

(i updated the route of the CSS, but the Javascript is missing an the images asweell)

I really would like not to have to correct al routes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` means the current directory, which isn't where the file is, so it doesn't work.

Your best bet is to start using paths relative to the root of your site from now on, every time you write a link to a stylesheet or javascript or image, on every site. It always works and saves you from problems like this.

`/css/style.css` points to the same URL no matter what directory the current page is in.

Comment: Yes, just this once. Once you start writing all your paths relative to the root of the site, you'll never have to change them due to changing the URL of a page again.