# Passing multiple parameters in htacess and including files based on them

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently am working on a project where I have to pass three parameters in the url. My url looks like -

**localhost/newproject/index.php?file_name=clients&mode=edit&id=1**

The functions that I perform when passing different parameters are listed below

1) **url** - **localhost/newproject/index.php?file_name=clients**

**Function** - include the file templates/modules/clients/clients.php

2) **url** - **localhost/newproject/index.php?file_name=clients&mode=edit**

**Function** - include the file template/modules/clients/cliemts-edit.php. And the clients-edit screen will be used to add a new client as the client id is not set.

3) **url** - **localhost/newproject/index.php?file_name=clients&mode=edit&id=1**

**Function** - include the file template/modules/clients/cliemts-edit.php. And the clients-edit screen will be used to update the client whose client_id is 1. Now, I am trying to convert this url to this

**localhost/newproject/clients/edit/1**

I have the following code in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?file_name=$1&mode=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?file_name=$1 [L]
```

The problem that I am facing is that whenever the clients-edit screen gets included, the path of the css files, javascript files and the images get changed. How can I overcome this?

Comment: if you're just using regular HTTP parameters, why would you even need a URL rewrite?

Comment: check out [this question about MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333093/how-to-implement-mvc-from-scratch-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with routes and mod-rewrite (if not absolute i don't get CSS, JS or images)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910376/problem-with-routes-and-mod-rewrite-if-not-absolute-i-dont-get-css-js-or-imag)

Comment: @NDM -  It makes the URL look more organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?file_name=$1&mode=$2&id=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?file_name=$1&mode=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?file_name=$1 [L]
```

In order to fix the css/scripts you need to either make your links absolute URLs (they start with a `/`) or include a relative URI base in the page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I actually have already defined the paths using $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] in a configuration file and used them as the paths. Still the page is not able to find the css files. I get one error showing that the page is actually looking for the css files in the page's directory. Haven't been able to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: @AnshulKumar if you right click on an image and copy the URL, what does that look like and what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: Jon: It got fixed. Thanks a lot for your help.

Earlier the links of the images looked like "http://locahost/newproject/templates/clients/images/icon1.png"

whereas it should've been "http://locahost/newproject/images/icon1.png"